# File not being deleted and renamed on Windows but is working on Mac

Tags: windows, macos

I wrote my code on Mac. 
I am creating two files, lets call them file1 and file2
For file1, if I find a greater record in SQL for a table than the one stored in the file1, I write everything to a temp file, delete file1 and rename the temp file to file1. This works both on Windows and Mac.

For file2, if I find a greater timestamp value in SQL for table than the one stored in file2, I do the same process. This is working locally on my Mac environment but fails to delete and rename the file on Windows.

However, when I first start the program, since my buffered writer is always writing into a temp file and then renaming the temp file, the renaming and deleting for file2 works the very first time I run the program, meaning file2 and neither file1 exist yet.

So upon start up, file2 doesn't exist. Buffered writer writes into tempFile, deletes file2 if it exists (in this case it doesn't), and renames tempFile to file2. This works. However subsequent recording of new data fails to delete and rename file2. But as I said this is working on Mac but not on Windows.

Code for deleting and rename file1 (works on windows and Mac):

```
private void recordMaxRecordIdFromHistory(String table, String maxRecord) {
    String line;
    try {
      File file1 = new File(file1);
      File tempFile = new File("tempFile.txt");

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, false);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      if (!file1.exists()) {
        file1.createNewFile();
      }
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file1);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

//writing to temp file
      if(){
        ....
      }
      else{
        ....
      }

      bw.close();
      br.close();
      if (file1.delete()) {
        logger.info("Successfully deleted the max ID file");
      } else {
        logger.error("Unable to delete the file maxID File");
      }
      if (tempFile.renameTo(file1)) {
        logger.info("Successfully renamed the tempFile to file1");
      } else {
        logger.error("Unable to rename the tempFile to file1");
      }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Code for deleting and renaming File2 (works on Mac and ONLY the first time program is ran on windows)

```
 private void recordLastModifiedDate(String table, Timestamp modifiedDate) {

    String line;

    try {
      File file2 = new File(file2);
      File tempFile2 = new File("tempFile2.txt");

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile2, false);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      if (!file2.exists()) {
        file2.createNewFile();
      }
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file2);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      //WRITING TO FILE HERE

      bw.close();
      br.close();

      if (file2.delete()) {
        logger.info("Successfully deleted the lastModified file");
      } else {
        logger.error("Unable to delete the lastModified file");
      }

      if (tempFile2.renameTo(file2)) {
        logger.info("Successfully renamed the tempFile to lastModified");
      } else {
        logger.error("Unable to rename the tempFile to lastModified");
      }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:batch-file]? Please read the tag info *before* applying tags!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the batch-file tag. I've removed it. Tags have specific meaning here. Please don't just randomly add those that sound familiar. Read the description before using any tag to make sure it's appropriate for your question. If you're not sure, don't add it and someone here will add it for you if it's needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing the `FileReader`, but the `BufferedReader` (same thing for the writers).

Since you don't close the `FileReader/FileWriter` (`fr.close()` and `fw.close()`), the handle stays active.

This is not a problem on Unix-like systems like MacOS-X but in Windows, you cannot delete a file if a program already has an open handle (read or write) on it (Windows *locks* the file), hence the error.

So call `fr.close()` and `fw.close()` and your code will work on Windows.

Comment: I added fr.close() and fw.close() after br.close()

Comment: So after adding fr.close and fw.close(), I thought that would solve the problem but there is a point in my code where I am reading the file as well. And i forgot to the close the file reader in that method. Adding fr.close in that block of code solved the problem.

Comment: Good news, I was suspecting that but couldn't tell it from your code. I'm glad that you found that yourself :)